# Getting null values from cellforrowatindexpath in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

Ha ii, i have this code in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  _lblmainChapterlbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:%@",delegate.selectedBook,delegate.selectedChapter,localStringValueverseno];

}
```

which i want to display lie Genesis1.1,but when i tap the cell containing Genesis1.1 on first i get Genesis1.(null),then i tap the second cell which contains Genesis1.2 i got the result of the first Genisis1.1.but there is no problem in delegate.Sewlectedbook and delegate.selectedchapter.the problem is in localStringValueverseno which contains verse number.i got null value on the first tap as i mentioned above.How can i solve it.plese help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have your tableview in a viewcontroller. I also guess `localStringValueverseno` is a NSString.
So in `initWith...` of your view controller, add the following line.

```
localStringValueverseno = @"0";
```

Initially it might not have any value and so you are getting null.

Comment: what is initwib???.i didn't understrant it.can i put thus localstringvalueverseno = @"0"in viewdidload??

Comment: Sorry, it was a little typo. I wanted to say `initWithNibName:bundle` or `initWithCoder:` method. Yeah, you can have it in `viewDidLoad` also, in your case.

Comment: i put this in viewdiload nd i get Genesis1.0 in the first tap.

Comment: localStringValueverseno = [(UILabel *)[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                                    viewWithTag:1] text];
_lblmainnotegns.text = localStringValueverseno; this is also in my didselectrowtintexpth

Comment: You have got Genesis1.0 on first tap. So now you are not getting null. So what is the problem? Also, please try to change your logic as you required.